# Python - modulus behavior different for separate and combined statements?

Tags: python, modulus

What is going on here?

```
print 'steps divided',125**(1.0/3), 5.0%1 
   >> steps divided 5.0 0.0
print 'steps combined',(125**(1.0/3))%1
   >> steps combined 1.0
```

Weirdly, the steps work for other numbers.... for example 8:

```
print 'steps divided',8**(1.0/3), 2.0%1
   >> steps divided 2.0 0.0
print 'steps combined',(8**(1.0/3))%1
   >> steps combined 0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this solves your problem...

```
>>> 125**(1.0/3), 5.0%1 
(4.999999999999999, 0.0)
>>> 4.999999999999%1
0.9999999999989999
```

`125**(1.0/3)` is really `4.999...`, not `5.0`.

Thus, you're doing `4.999999999999999%1`, which gives you the output of `.0.9999999999989999`, which gets rounded to 1.

Comment: Yeah I figured it was a rounding issue... so the print command is rounding 4.99999999 up? why is 8 accurate, and 125 not? I'm looking for an elegant solution.

Comment: ahh I guess it's because 1.0/3 is 0.3333333 which isn't really a pure 1/3 like 0.5 is for 1/2. Is there a way around this without rounding? The purpose of this is to determine if the cube root is a whole number.

Comment: @MattTakao Unfortunately, not to my knowledge.